# AngularJS: Unable to determine your location

Tags: angularjs

i am a newbie of anugularJS, so probably i am doing something wrong. My angular version is 1.6.4. For geolocation i am using this module [angularjs-geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-geolocation). Here is the demo of geolocation module [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/TM71LBh6ttYotOo6t7oX/preview). By including this module in my project and testing on a browser gives me this error. I have followed all the steps but i am missing something.

> Possibly unhandled rejection: Unable to determine your location

This is my user-settings.component.js file:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var module = angular.module(__appName);

    function controller($http, geolocation) {
        var model = this;

        model.location = function () {
            console.log("inside");

            model.coords = geolocation.getLocation().then(function (data) {
                return { lat: data.coords.latitude, long: data.coords.longitude };
            });
       }

    }

    module.component("userSettings", {
        templateUrl: "components/user-settings/user-settings.template.html",
        bindings: {
            userId: "<"
        },
        controllerAs: "model",
        controller: ["$http", "geolocation", controller]
    });

}());
```

This is my user-settings.template.html file:

```
<div class="text-center">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="model.location()">Location</button>
   {{model.coords}}
</div>
```

My App.js file:

```
angular.module(__appName, ["geolocation"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run the following code in my local machine:

```
<html>    
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0-rc2" data-semver="1.2.0-rc2" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation/master/dist/angularjs-geolocation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <p>Your location is: {{coords}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
<script>
angular.module('myApp',['geolocation'])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope,geolocation) {
    geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data){
      $scope.coords = {lat:data.coords.latitude, long:data.coords.longitude};
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

And it worked. It's nothing dissimilar to yours. The location not showing in the **Plunker** might be a **Plunker** issue.

Try it in your local server. It will work.